# HTML - compatibility with Internet Explorer and Firefox for Button

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I made a chunk of code for a html button that link to a website I did.
I made the button following w3 school tutorials.
It is working when browsing with Chrome, Edge, and Safari, unfortunately it is not the case with Internet Explorer 11 and Firefox Quantum (58.0)...
To be more clear, the button is displayed correctly, but clicking on it do not load the website page.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
      .bluebutton {
      padding: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 200%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      background-color: #337ab7;
      border-radius: 7px;
      box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 3px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
      }  
      .bluebutton:hover {background-color: #3e8e41}
      .bluebutton:active {
      background-color: #3e8e41;
      transform: translateY(5px);
      }
      .bluebutton span {
      cursor: pointer;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      transition: 0.5s;
      }
      .bluebutton span:after {
      content: '\00bb';
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      top: 0;
      right: -20px;
      transition: 0.5s;
      }
      .bluebutton:hover span {
      padding-right: 25px;
      }
      .bluebutton:hover span:after {
      opacity: 1;
      right: 0;
      } 
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <button class="bluebutton">
   <a href="https://www.youtube.com" style="color: white">
   <span>Access Website</span>
   </a>
   </button>
</body>
</html>
```

If possible I would like to keep the css style part inside the html code.
I would be grateful for you help.
Best regards,

Comment: Please explain what is not working

Comment: try  `appearance: none;`and `border: none;` on `.bluebutton`

Comment: @Huangism the button is displayed correctly but the when clicking it, it doesn't redirect to the webpage. The link seems to not work.

Comment: @LuisP.A. Sorry it is not working I put it like this in the code:  
 
      .bluebutton {
      appearance: none;
      border: none;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 200%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      background-color: #337ab7;
      border-radius: 7px;
      box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 3px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
      }  

Did I miss something ?  
I also tried with -webkit-appearance instead. does not work better.

Comment: @YoannPageaud put anchor tag outside of the button, in other words, wrap the button with the anchor. Or just use anchor tag only and style it like a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found a solution to my problem !
First I would like to quote @Silverman42 who also had the same idea than me when I was trying to find an answer in the mean time: using `<a>` tag is the first key to solve the compatibility problem. It works for all web browsers cited in my question.
The other key was to replace the CSS style options `width: 100%;` , `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;` by `display: block;` to create a block for the element and then just `text-align: center` to center back the text of the link on the button.
See below complete solution that worked for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
      .bluebutton {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 200%;
      background-color: #337ab7;
      border-radius: 7px;
      box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 3px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
      }  
      .bluebutton:hover {background-color: #3e8e41}
      .bluebutton:active {
      background-color: #3e8e41;
      transform: translateY(5px);
      }
      .bluebutton span {
      cursor: pointer;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      transition: 0.5s;
      }
      .bluebutton span:after {
      content: '\00bb';
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      top: 0;
      right: -20px;
      transition: 0.5s;
      }
      .bluebutton:hover span {
      padding-right: 25px;
      }
      .bluebutton:hover span:after {
      opacity: 1;
      right: 0;
      } 
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <a href="https://www.youtube.com" class="bluebutton" style="color: white">
   <span>Access Website</span>
   </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could easily just do most of the button customization on the `<a>` tag without the need for  using the `<button>`tag.

Comment: You are right this is what I was testing in the mean time and this seems to be more easy for firefox to understand.

Comment: You had the good idea. I cited you in the solution that worked for me.

Comment: Glad I could be of help!!